# Unabale to add a foreign key in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am writing these database tables, but I am getting this error:

> Error Code: 3734. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing
> column 'semester' for constraint 'grade_ibfk_3' in the referenced
> table 'Enrolement'    0.0012 sec

I don't know why. I looked at similar problems but still can't find solution for my problem. What I want to create is the Grade Table. Thanks for help in advance.

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
stud_id int unsigned not null,
stud_name varchar(30) not null,
stud_phone varchar(10) not null,
stud_date_of_birth varchar(10) not null,
stud_city varchar(50) not null,
stud_adress varchar(100) not null,
stud_postcode char(4) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(stud_id) 
);

CREATE TABLE Subject
(
subj_code char(8) not null,
subj_title varchar(50) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (subj_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Enrolement
(
stud_id int unsigned not null,
subj_code char(8) not null,
semester smallint unsigned not null DEFAULT 1,
year smallint unsigned not null,
commnet varchar(500) null,
PRIMARY KEY (stud_id, subj_code ,semester, year),
FOREIGN KEY(stud_id) REFERENCES Student(stud_id),
FOREIGN KEY(subj_code) REFERENCES Subject(subj_code)
);

CREATE TABLE Grade
(
stud_id int unsigned not null,
subj_code char(8) not null unique,
semester smallint unsigned not null DEFAULT 1,
year smallint unsigned not null,
grade char(2) null,
PRIMARY KEY(stud_id, subj_code, semester, year),
FOREIGN KEY(stud_id) REFERENCES Student(stud_id),
FOREIGN KEY(subj_code) REFERENCES Subject(subj_code),
FOREIGN KEY (semester) REFERENCES Enrolement (semester),
FOREIGN KEY (year) REFERENCES Enrolement (year)
);
```

Comment: The referenced column is missing an index.  In Enrolement, add `index (semester)`.  Note: there are other similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust Enrolement as follows, to add the missing indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE Enrolement
(
stud_id int unsigned not null,
subj_code char(8) not null,
semester smallint unsigned not null DEFAULT 1,
year smallint unsigned not null,
commnet varchar(500) null,
index (semester),
index (year),
PRIMARY KEY (stud_id, subj_code ,semester, year),
FOREIGN KEY(stud_id) REFERENCES Student(stud_id),
FOREIGN KEY(subj_code) REFERENCES Subject(subj_code)
);
```

Fiddle:

[Adjusted schema](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1f1c48af5b4e1b1560c4563a9700111)